# asp.net basic routing not working

Tags: asp.net, routes, url-routing

I'm working on asp.net web forms and i got some issue with routing, following route is not working:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new Route("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}", new StopRoutingHandler()));    
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("category", "en/Product/{ProductName}", "~/en/index.aspx");
```

url i'm tring is:
http://localhost:5562/en/Product.aspx?ProductName=Laptop

Comment: Try `http://localhost:5562/en/Product/Laptop` as your browser route.

Comment: thanks for reply: its working with your mentioned url but i have to use this url: "http://localhost:5562/en/Product.aspx?ProductName=Laptop"

Comment: The purpose of a route is to prevent you needing to use your ASPX page URL.  The route is mapped to index.aspx and not product.aspx.  So you create a new route or amend your existing one, or don't use a route at all.

Comment: and if i have to prevent some product names not allowed in url then what?
like i like to not allow this url:
http://localhost:5562/en/Product/computer
or
http://localhost:5562/en/Product.aspx?ProductName=computer

Comment: I've posted an answer to address your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `http://localhost:5562/en/Product/Laptop` as your browser route.

Then, based on your comments, if you want to forbid a value, do this in your code that reads the value, within index.aspx (or product.aspx if you're using that):

```
string value = Page.RouteData.Values("ProductName"); // get the product being searched for from the URL
List<string> forbiddenValues = new List<string> { "Computer", "BadWord2", "BadWord3" }; // put your forbidden terms in here
if (forbiddenValues.Contains(s, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) // case-insensitive
{
    // Bad value detect - throw error or do something
    MyLiteral.Text = "Bad term found.  Cannot continue";
} else
{
    // do you database stuff here and get the products
}
```